# Max and min value of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $n$ is integer: 
$$a(n) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n-1}$$
then

1. $a(100) \leq 100$
2. $a(100) > 100$
3. $a(200) \leq 100$
4. $a(200) > 100$

I tried to solve this question by limiting it with GP but not reaching any conclusion. Also gave a thought to convert it to Integration.  Any thought ??

Comment: Thanx everyone for help

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough (and not involving transcendental functions) approximation for $a(n)$ can be obtained as follows:

If we replace each summand $\frac1k$ with $\frac1{2^r}$ where $r$ is determined by $2^r\le k<2^{r+1}$, we find for $n\ge2$
$$a(n)< {1+\underbrace{\frac12+\frac12}_{=1}+\underbrace{\frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14}_{=1}+\ldots+\underbrace{\frac1{2^{n-1}}+\ldots+\frac1{2^{n-1}}}_{=1}}=n$$ 
If we take $\frac1{2^{r+1}}$ instead, we arrive at 
$$a(n)>\frac n2 $$

Hence 1 and 4 are correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is approximately is $\ln(n)$ for big $N$. So, $a(100)$ is $\ln(2^{100})+1$ approximately but a little less than $100 * ln(2) + 1 \approx 70$, and $a(200)$ is near $200\ln(2)+1 \approx 140$. Therefore, $a(200) > 100$.

$$a(100) < 100$$
$$a(200) > 100$$

You can see the approximation as harmonic series in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)).

Comment: Minor detail that doesn't affect the answer, but where are you getting the $+1$ from?

Comment: You can see the details in this link:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)
Anyhow, we know that $\forall k\in N: \sum_0^k\frac{1}{n} \leq ln(k) + 1$.

Comment: (It should be $+\gamma$) -edit: I just saw that you have it as an upper bound.... again this is no big deal since it's a small correction at these values, but I was confused

Comment: You're right. However, I've considered the worst case.